# Redirect on main window after payment

Tags: javascript, redirect, payment

I am doing payment related work on my website. I am facing a issue related to redirection. So to make you understand the problem let me take an example.

Lets say I am on `https://www.foo.com/`(lets say it foo) and I click a button on this webpage to open a new window using `window.open(url,'_blank');` whose url is `https://www.paymentwebsite.com` (lets say it goo), after the payment is done goo takes me to `https://foo.com/paymentresult` (lets say it foo-pr) in the same window which goo was opened but what I want is that goo should open foo-pr in the window which foo was opened.

How can I do this ?

Comment: Your example is confusing me, are you saying you want the redirect to happen on the page where the button is clicked? if so you should rather use `window.location.href = url`

Comment: Don’t open this in a popup to begin with, but in the current window ... then the user will land back on your site in the original window without any extra effort.

Comment: @CBroe Previously I was opening in the oroginal window but problem I am facing with that is after I come to foo-pr and I click browser back button it takes me to payment page again but I wanted to go place where button was clicked(foo)

Comment: @Andre Marques Previously on button click I was using window.location.href to open in the same window but I was facing a problem that after payment was done I was taken to foo-pr and when I clicked back button of browser again I was taken to payment page but actually what I wanted was I wanted to go to the webpage where button was clicked(foo)

Comment: Well then you can at most close the popup and redirect the original window somewhere else, from within your target page that gets loaded into the popup. (How to - please research first.)

Answer (score 0):

What is understand is that you want the popup window to redirect to the same url as its parent is on like you said foo.

after you are done with the payment work and want to redirect to foo just use the following code.

```
window.location.href = window.opener.document.location.href;
```

window.opener will point to the parent window and it will load that page.